# can I run gridmix3 on hadoop-0.20.203.0?How?

Tags: hadoop, benchmarking

I use hadoop-0.20.203.0. In some reasons,I should use this version of hadoop.And I can't change the version of hadoop.In this version of hadoop, there are gridmix and gridmix2 benchmarks.But I want to run some applications  in benchmark which there aren't in gridmix and gridmix2.(such as wordcount,Grep,Terasort).what should I do?can I use gridmix3 in hadoop-0.20.203.0?or is there a way to add these applications to Gridmix or Gridmix2?
I am new to hadoop...please help me...